# Create an interface with a method that's 'generic', but it's generic type is the implementer of the interface

Tags: c#, generics, interface

Is there any way in C# to have a generic type that is always the implementing type in an interface? Something like this:

```
interface Foo
{
    this GetOtherThis();
}

class Bar : Foo
{
    Bar GetOtherThis();
}
```

Comment: Side note: The question was asked many times, but there is essentially no way to find duplicate as there is no common terminology around the problem. Part of where class depends on itself called [Curiously recurring template](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), but it is not common enough to give you search results...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Huh, interesting.

Comment: *Why* do you need this? This sounds like an X/Y problem to me, which problem are you trying to solve for which this seems like a good solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any way in C# to have a generic type that is always the implementing type in an interface?

No. The answers given so far *don't* satisfy this, for two reasons:

- You can always implement an interface with a different `T`

  ```
  interface IFoo<T>
  {
      T GetOtherThis();
  }

  public class NotAString : Foo<string>
  {
      string GetOtherThis() { ... }
  }
  ```

  This can be fixed *somewhere* with a constraint: `interface IFoo<T> where T : IFoo<T>` but that still doesn't stop this;

  ```
  public class Good : IFoo<Good> { ... }

  public class Evil : IFoo<Good> { /* Mwahahahaha */ }
  ```
- Inheritance breaks it anyway:

  ```
  interface IFoo<T>
  {
      T GetOtherThis();
  }

  public class WellBehaved : IFoo<WellBehaved>
  {
      WellBehaved GetOtherThis() { ... }
  }

  public class BadlyBehaved : WellBehaved
  {
      // Ha! Now x.GetOtherThis().GetType() != x.GetType()
  }
  ```

Basically there's nothing in C# which will enforce this for you. If you trust interface implementations to be sensible, then the generic interface scheme is still useful, but you need to understand its limitations.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you could write your code using a generic interface:

```
interface Foo<T>
{
    T GetOtherThis();
}

class Bar : Foo<Bar>
{
    Bar GetOtherThis();
}
```

**Note:** There is no generic constraint you can put on `T` to make `T` be the implementing class. Jon Skeet explains it much better detail.

Comment: Right, I know I can use this, but is there anyway I can force whatever implements foo to implement it as Foo<itself>, or must it implement it itself? That's what I'm looking for.

Comment: @AlphaMCubed I don't think so. That would be a generic type constraint, as in the other answer, but you can't force it to be itself, just to derive from a given class, have a constructor, etc.

Comment: darn. Well okay then.